# Use case of initiating login from a third party

Tags: openid-connect

Section 4 of the Open Id Connect 1.0 Core specification states:

> In some cases, the login flow is initiated by an OpenID Provider or another party, rather than the Relying Party. In this case, the initiator redirects to the RP at its login initiation endpoint, which requests that the RP send an Authentication Request to a specified OP. This login initiation endpoint can be a deep link at the RP, rather than a default landing page. RPs supporting OpenID Connect Dynamic Client Registration 1.0 [OpenID.Registration] register this endpoint value using the initiate_login_uri Registration parameter.
>
> The party initiating the login request does so by redirecting to the login initiation endpoint at the RP, passing the following parameters:
>
> iss
>   REQUIRED. Issuer Identifier for the OP that the RP is to send the Authentication Request to. Its value MUST be a URL using the https scheme.
>   login_hint
>   OPTIONAL. Hint to the Authorization Server about the login identifier the End-User might use to log in. If the client receives a value for this string-valued parameter, it MUST include it in the Authentication Request as the login_hint parameter value.
>   target_link_uri
>   OPTIONAL. URL that the RP is requested to redirect to after authentication. RPs MUST verify the value of the target_link_uri to prevent being used as an open redirector to external sites.
>   The parameters can either be passed as query parameters using the HTTP GET method or be passed as HTML form values that are auto-submitted in the User Agent, and thus are transmitted via the HTTP POST method.
>
> Other parameters MAY be sent, if defined by extensions. Any parameters used that are not understood MUST be ignored by the Client.
>
> Clients SHOULD employ frame busting and other techniques to prevent End-Users from being logged in by third party sites without their knowledge through attacks such as Clickjacking. Refer to Section 4.4.1.9 of [RFC6819] for more details.

Suppose I have a RP client foo registered at the OP service.com, I would like to know how does it fit in the use case that client foo instructs instructs the OP service.com to relay the request to another OP like google. And how does the RP eventually receives the id_token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not fit in your use-case:

- foo is a RP and thus can be the initiator: section 4 says *the login flow is initiated by an OpenID Provider or another party*
- but foo can not instruct service.com to relay to google, since service.com is an OP, not a RP, and section 4 only talks about redirecting to a RP: *The party initiating the login request does so by redirecting to the login initiation endpoint at the RP*.

Therefore, section 4 does not apply to your use-case.

A way to match your use-case would be to let service.com act simultaneously as an OP and a SP: service.com can act as an OP for foo and as a SP for google. An example of such a use-case is implemented by [FranceConnect](https://partenaires.franceconnect.gouv.fr/fcp/fournisseur-service). This is a French public service, that acts as an IdP (OP) in front of its customers (French public services, for health insurance for instance) and a RP (SP) in front of french public identity providers (some public administrations, like the public department of finances). This way, the end-user connects to an initial service, the service redirects this user to FranceConnect as an OP, FranceConnect as a SP redirects this user to another OP, this final OP redirects back the user to FranceConnect, that get the user's identity from the final OP, then redirects the user to the initial service, that gets the user's identity from FranceConnect (FranceConnect knows the identity because it has gotten it from the final OP previously).

Here is an UML sequence diagram for this use-case:

[image: UML sequence diagram]

Comment: Thanks Alex for such detailed answer. Yeah that flow is exactly what I would like to achieve. Good to know section 4 isn't talking about this.